# QCheckbox: more states than checked and unchecked

Tags: c++, qt, qcheckbox

Is it possible to have more states for `QCheckbox` than `Qt::Checked` and `Qt::Unchecked`?
I have a `QTreeWidget` and if an Item is checked I want the parent to show a filled checkbox (some state like "Child checked") and the children should then have a state like "parent checked". If latter would be too complex to achieve I think the normal `Qt::Checked` would also work fine. But how to achieve the first? Here is my code how I am currently adding items with checkboxes:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* Options::folderMonitoringCreateTreeCheckbox(QDir *dir, bool state, QTreeWidget *parent)
{
    QString text = dir->absolutePath().section('/', -1, -1, QString::SectionSkipEmpty);    

    QTreeWidgetItem *newItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(parent);
    newItem->setText(0,text);
    newItem->setFlags(newItem->flags() | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
    newItem->setCheckState(0, Qt::Unchecked);
    newItem->setToolTip(0, dir->absolutePath());    
    return newItem;
}
```

Here is a Screenshot for what I want to achieve (screenshot taken from MediaMonkey):
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: What about Qt::PartiallyChecked?

Comment: @Fabio Thank you! I always googled for "filled qcheckbox" and couldn't find anything like that! :)

Comment: The first time I saw partially checked checkbox in Qt was inside the Qt SDK installer. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`Qt::PartiallyChecked`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#CheckState-enum), the description of it says:

> The item is partially checked. Items in hierarchical models may be partially checked if some, but not all, of their children are checked.

Comment: Thank you, as I already said in comment of my post: I was searching for "filled qcheckbox" and could not find anything like that, thats exactly what I need.